# LinqToSQL removing specific child nodes from a list of parent nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

I have an `ObservableCollection` of recipes, and each recipe has an `ObservableCollection` of ingredients.  Let's say that I'm wanting to modify or remove a certain ingredient from all of the recipes (for instance, to remove peanuts from all of the recipes) using Linq.  I have tried doing something like this:

```
foreach(Recipe r in myObservableRecipes) 
{
    r.ObservableIngredients.RemoveAll(i => i.Type == PEANUTS);
}
```

This doesn't work though because the ingredients list is an ObservableCollection and `RemoveAll` is a `List<T>` method.  If I add `ToList().RemoveAll()` it doesn't actually remove them from the collection, but removes them from a copy of the collection.  I can't find a Remove Where combination that seems to work, as Where returns an `IEnumerable` which does not have a `Remove` call.

What I'm doing is:

```
foreach(Recipe r in myObservableRecipes)
{
    var ingToRemove = new HashSet<Ingredient>(r.myObservableIngredients.Where(i => i.Type == PEANUTS));
    foreach (Ingredient i in r.myObservableIngredients.ToList())
    {
        if(ingToRemove.Contains(i)) r.myObservableIngredients.Remove(i);
    }
    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("myObservableIngredients");
}
```

This works but seems clunky where the intersection of the entity sets and observable collections are.  I'm actually also removing the same entity from the entity set (`DeleteOnSubmit`) inside the same loop, and then calling submit changes.  Is this the design intent for using `LinqToSQL` entities with WPF and the `ObservableCollections/CollectionViewSource` paradigm?

Comment: If you're removing an ingredient from all recipes, can't you remove them from that table without regard to the recipe to which each belongs?

Comment: @madreflection In my simplified model that is the case.  In my actual model I have a select property that I need to remove, so its all children with a common field value that could be a foreign key but is not at the moment.

Comment: You should add that to the question in detail. It's not yet a [mre] because it's too underdeveloped to describe the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using an `ObservableCollection<T>` is that you can add or remove items from it and have the UI updated without creating any additional collections.

Just use a nested plain-old `for` loop:

```
for (int i = myObservableRecipes.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    Recipe r = myObservableRecipes[i];
    for (int j = r.myObservableIngredients.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        Ingredient ing = r.myObservableIngredients[j];
        if (ing.Type == PEANUTS)
            r.myObservableIngredients.RemoveAt(j);
    }
    //remove recipes without any remaining ingredients
    if (r.myObservableIngredients.Count == 0)
        myObservableRecipes.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

This is not "clunky" compared to iterating the same collection more than once using LINQ and creating additional collections.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear enough, but when you use Linq2SQL you end up with collections of entities, and in order to populate the UI you then build the ObservableCollections with the same entities.  But this means that you need two sets of interactions: one to update the UI and another to update the database.  That is what seems clunky to me, but it seems to be by design.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many collections you have. It is the entity objects that gets updated and a single entity object can belong to more than one collection. What's your issue?

Comment: That by design I'm managing one collection for the UI and a separate collection for the model.  To me this seems klunky.  I know that they are the same entities (though when I began doing this 5 years ago I didn't realize that and wrote a synchronization layer which exposed this).  So I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious that somehow ties these collections together.  The other part of my question is once the UI provides the parameter to filer the child collections on, is there a great linq way to remove from all of the child collections any that has that parameter.

Comment: @PaulGibson: No, there is nothing that connects the collections themselves.